# JQuery clear $(this) object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prefill the phone number fields with format for different countries US,Canada(xxx) xxx-xxxx and for rest of the countries as +xxxxxxx.The problem here is when i change country the logic does not seem to be working since the Jquery object is holding previous value.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dap3L426/19/)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#country').on('change', function() {

    if (this.value == 'US' || this.value == 'CA') {

      $('#C_BusPhone')
      .keydown(function(e) {

        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;

        $phone = $(this);

        if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
          if ($phone.val().length === 4) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + ')');
          }
          if ($phone.val().length === 5) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
          }
          if ($phone.val().length === 9) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + '-');
          }
        }
        return (key == 8 ||
          key == 9 ||
          key == 46 ||
          (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
          (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
      })

      .bind('focus click', function() {
        $phone = $(this);

        if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
          $phone.val('(');
        } else {
          var val = $phone.val();
          $phone.val('').val(val);
        }
      })

      .blur(function() {
        $phone = $(this);

        if ($phone.val() === '(') {
          $phone.val('');
        }
      });

    } else {

      $('#C_BusPhone')
      .keydown(function(e) {
       if ($(this).val().indexOf("+") === -1) {
          $(this).val("+" + $(this).val());
        }
      })

    }


  });
});
```

Comment: you can't have `.bind()` and `.on()` in the same code  , `.bind() `is for older depricated versions , and `.on()` is the new way , I don't think any versions allow both to work

Comment: and you have to write `var $phone = $(this);`  without the `var` you are making it global and actually assigning to the same property

Comment: The problem is it works correctly for the first time but when i change the drop down value and try reentering the information its holding the prefix from the previous drop down country

Comment: did you add the `var` in both spots  like I said?

Comment: because when you add the event it stays attached. It is not removed or overwritten...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#country').on('change', function() {

  $('#C_BusPhone').val("");
  alert($("#country").val());
});

$('#C_BusPhone').keydown(function(e) {

    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    var phone = $('#C_BusPhone');

    if ($("#country").val() == 'US' || $("#country").val() == 'CA') {
        console.log($("#country").val());

        if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
          if (phone.val().length === 4) {
            phone.val(phone.val() + ')');
          }
          if (phone.val().length === 5) {
            phone.val(phone.val() + ' ');
          }
          if (phone.val().length === 9) {
            phone.val(phone.val() + '-');
          }
        }

       if (phone.val().length === 0) {
          phone.val('(');
       } 
       else {
          var val = phone.val();
          phone.val('').val(val);
       }

     } 
     else {

       if (phone.val().indexOf("+") === -1) {
          phone.val("+" + phone.val());
       }
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just keep on adding events, they do not get overwritten. So you need to manually remove the event. Since you are using `bind()` it would be `unbind()`.

```
$('#C_BusPhone').unbind("keydown");
```

Note that per [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), for 1.7+ using `on()` and `off()` is preferred over `bind()` and `unbind()`.

Another option is just to attach one event and do the logic check inside of what code to run.